# iOS: How to make my image logo at the top of the page SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

firstly I am really new to iOS development and Swift (2 weeks coming here from PHP :))

I am building my simple Login page and wondering how to make my Logo image at the top of the page. Also I am wondering if I have done my layout wrong to get the desired layout as in the screenshot. Would appreciate the help on this.
(Logo scribbled out in the screen shot needs to go to the top outside the white background)

Thanks

LoginView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View {
    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    let verticalPaddingForForm = 40
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color(red: 20/225.0 ,green: 22/225.0 , blue: 25/225.0)
        
            
            
            VStack(spacing: CGFloat(verticalPaddingForForm)) {
                
                Image("logo")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                
                Divider()
                
                VStack {
                        TextField("Email", text: $email)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 30).padding(.top, 20)
                        Divider()
                            .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 30).padding(.top, 20)
                        Divider()
                            .padding(.horizontal, 30)

                }
                .background(Color(.white))
                
                
                Text("Forgotten Password")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .font(.system(size: 15))
                
                Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                    Text("Login")
                        .padding()
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                    
                }
                .background(Color.black)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.top, 0)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, CGFloat(verticalPaddingForForm))
            .background(Color(.white))
            
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                    Text("Register")
                        .padding()
                        .font(.system(size: 40))

                    
                }
                .background(Color(red: 20/225.0 ,green: 22/225.0 , blue: 25/225.0))
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding()
            }
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
        

    };
}
```

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
    
}


extension UIDevice {
    var hasNotch: Bool {
        let bottom = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
        return bottom > 0
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code-:

Use a `ZStack` to give a `backgroundColor` to your view, and give that a modifier of `.ignoresSafeArea()`.

Use `VStack` inside `ZStack` to layout other view components. I have done few modifications on my side.

```
   struct LoginView: View {
    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    let verticalPaddingForForm = 40
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack() {
            Color(red: 20/225.0 ,green: 22/225.0 , blue: 25/225.0).ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack(spacing:15){
                
                 Image(systemName: “logo")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame( height: 200)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .padding([.top],15)
                
                VStack(spacing: CGFloat(verticalPaddingForForm)) {
                    
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Email", text: $email)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 30).padding(.top, 20)
                        Divider()
                            .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 30).padding(.top, 20)
                        Divider()
                            .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                        
                    }
                    .background(Color(.white))
                    .padding([.top])
                    
                    
                    Text("Forgotten Password")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                    
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Text("Login")
                            .padding()
                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                        
                    }
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding([.bottom])
                    
                    
                }
                .background(Color(.white))
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Register")
                        .padding()
                        .font(.system(size: 40))
                }
                
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                
            }
            
        }
        
    };
}


struct Test1: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
    
}


extension UIDevice {
    var hasNotch: Bool {
        let bottom = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
        return bottom > 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `ZStack (alignment: .top)` to set the alignment from the top. And then you can use a `Spacer()` at the end of the second `VStack` to expand the view.

The following code works for me. It's your code with little changes. Also, I suggest you create a subview to better organize your code, instead of writing all views within the same view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View {
    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    let verticalPaddingForForm = 40
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack (alignment: .top){
            Color(red: 20/225.0 ,green: 22/225.0 , blue: 25/225.0)
            
            VStack(spacing: CGFloat(verticalPaddingForForm)) {
                
                Image(systemName: "gear")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 100)
                
                Divider()
                
                VStack {
                    TextField("Email", text: $email)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 30).padding(.top, 20)
                    Divider()
                        .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                    SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 30).padding(.top, 20)
                    Divider()
                        .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                    
                }
                .background(Color(.white))
                
                
                Text("Forgotten Password")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .font(.system(size: 15))
                
                Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                    Text("Login")
                        .padding()
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                    
                }
                .background(Color.black)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.top, 0)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, CGFloat(verticalPaddingForForm))
            .background(Color(.white))
            
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                    Text("Register")
                        .padding()
                        .font(.system(size: 40))
                    
                    
                }
                .background(Color(red: 20/225.0 ,green: 22/225.0 , blue: 25/225.0))
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `Spacer()` between `Image("logo")` and `Divider()` to push your logo to the top of the screen